# Install laravel in shared hosting website's subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

im trying to install Laravel in my shared hosting website's(which is not laravel) subfolder.
for example in: example.com/dev

Structure:

```
->laravel
  ->app
  ->bootstrap
->public_html
  ...example.com folders & files
  ->dev
    ->css
    ->js
    ->.htacess
    ->index.php
    ... other Laravel public files
```

My example.com/dev/index.php looks like this:

```
... laravel codes

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

... laravel codes
```

**Problem:**
When i try to enter http://example.com/dev/ browser throws error:

This page isn’t working 
mysite.com didn’t send any data. 
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

THERE ARE NO ANY INFORMATION/SOLUTION FOR THIS PROBLEM IN THE INTERNET.

**ANY SOLUTION?**

Answer (score 0):

Your entire project should be inside your `public_html` folder. Then move all the contents of your public folder to `public_html` as well. Then edit your index.php to match the proper directory for `autoload.php` and `app.php`

Comment: Then what's the `Laravel` folder doing outside your `public_html`?

Comment: I dont understand, what is the problem with laravel folder destination

Comment: "Your entire project should be inside your public_html folder."

Answer (score 0):

From your text I assume you want call Laravel via http://example.com/dev/ If you hoster allows symlinks, you can try this.

```
-> laravel
  -> app
  -> ...
  -> public // symlinked to public_html/example.com/dev
  -> ...

-> public_html
  -> example.com folders & files
    -> dev // This is a symlink to laravel/public
```

A better approach in my opinion would be to create a subdomain and call Laravel like [http://dev.example.com](http://dev.example.com/). It depends on your hoster how you can do this.